# Redux actions : meaning of returning an object with a key but no value?

Tags: javascript, redux

In https://redux.js.org/basics/actions, it shows an action creator returning an object.

That object has a key `text` but no value or semi-colon. Is that a new ecmascript feature? What does it mean?

```
function addTodo(text) {
  return {
    type: ADD_TODO,
    text
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an object initializer, a property name without a value implies that the value of a like-named variable in scope should be used. It's therefore the same as

```
function addTodo(text) {
  return {
    type: ADD_TODO,
    text: text
  }
}
```

This syntax was introduced with ES2015. It's called [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions)

Comment: Great answer 1 min after I ask the question... that's why I don't bother searching!!!